# Adding a table in impresspages cms 4

Tags: impresspages

I was using an older version for one client but when I installed a new setup on 4.x I noticed when editing the page content, there is no option for a table? Is this no longer supported? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default text widget has table functionality. It's the last icon on the first row.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it was there. Thanks